# Perform search on HTML nagular js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
I am need to perform search on the below code ..

When I type something on search textbox all table data is hiding but never coming back. what is happening here..please help me on this
```

my search textbox is inside the body of the table and panels are required, can't remove those panels

---

When I type something on search textbox all table data is hiding but never coming back. what is happening here..please help me on this

my search textbox is inside the body of the table and panels are required, can't remove those

---

When I type something on search textbox all table data is hiding but never coming back. what is happening here..please help me on this

my search textbox is inside the body of the table and panels are required, can't remove those

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

js code:

```
enter code here
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Search on name column only
            $('#SearchValue').keyup(function () {
                // Search Text
                var search = $(this).val();

                // Hide all table tbody rows
                $('table tbody tr').hide();

                // Count total search result
                var len = $('table tbody tr: td:nth-child(1):contains("' + search + '")').length;

                if (len > 0) {
                    // Searching text in columns and show match row
                    $('table tbody tr: td:contains("' + search + '")').each(function () {
                        $(this).closest('tr').show();
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $('table tbody tr').show();
                }

            });

        });

        //// Case-insensitive searching (Note - remove the below script for Case sensitive search )
        //$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function (arg) {
        //    return function (elem) {
        //        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
        //    };
        //});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 sideBlock">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Site Details Search:
                <input type="text" id="SearchValue" placeholder=" search name"/>


            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive" id="SiteDetails" style="height:430px;overflow-y: auto;">
                    <table class="table table-hover" id="tblSiteDetails">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="test testremove" id="Site46">
                                <td class="Normal">&nbsp;&nbsp;1. AnotherTestSite<button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-grey btn-xs" id="site_46" onclick="ChangeColorforSensor('Site46', 'Normal'); ShowSitePopup('[object Object]', '(38.627002, -90.199404)', 'AnotherTestSite', '46', 'Normal', '8050 West Florissant',  'CSK Ltd.',  '2');">Normal</button></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="test testremove" id="Site43">
                                <td class="Normal">&nbsp;&nbsp;2. CB2<button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-grey btn-xs" id="site_43" onclick="ChangeColorforSensor('Site43', 'Normal'); ShowSitePopup('[object Object]', '(25.556044, 84.66033)', 'CB2', '43', 'Normal', 'HYD',  'CSK Ltd.',  '1');">Normal</button></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="test testremove" id="Site48">
                                <td class="Normal">&nbsp;&nbsp;3. Eswar-TestSite<button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-success btn-xs" id="site_48" onclick="ChangeColorforSensor('Site48', 'Normal'); ShowSitePopup('[object Object]', '(17.385044, 78.486671)', 'Eswar-TestSite', '48', 'Normal', 'plot 203, pushparesidency, kamalanagar, medipalli, Uppal',  '3334',  '1');">Normal</button></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="test testremove" id="Site32"><td class="Critical">&nbsp;&nbsp;4. FFT_Test_Site<button type="button" class="pull-right  btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="site_32" onclick="ChangeColorforSensor('Site32', 'Critical'); ShowSitePopup('[object Object]', '(17.451788, 78.372044)', 'FFT_Test_Site', '32', 'Critical', 'TMTC',  'CSK Ltd.',  '3');">Critical</button></td></tr>
                            <tr class="test testremove" id="Site35"><td class="Critical">&nbsp;&nbsp;5. NMC<button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-grey btn-xs" id="site_35" onclick="ChangeColorforSensor('Site35', 'Critical'); ShowSitePopup('[object Object]', '(38.627002, -90.199404)', 'NMC', '35', 'Critical', '8050 W. Florissant Ave',  'Test Motor Corporation',  '1');">Critical</button></td></tr>
                            <tr class="test testremove" id="Site38"><td class="Normal">&nbsp;&nbsp;6. PROD SETUP<button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-grey btn-xs" id="site_38" onclick="ChangeColorforSensor('Site38', 'Normal'); ShowSitePopup('[object Object]', '(38.627002, -90.199404)', 'PROD SETUP', '38', 'Normal', 'St Louis',  'Test Motor Corporation',  '1');">Normal</button></td></tr>
                            <tr class="test testremove" id="Site39"><td class="Critical">&nbsp;&nbsp;7. Plexus_Site<button type="button" class="pull-right  btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="site_39" onclick="ChangeColorforSensor('Site39', 'Critical'); ShowSitePopup('[object Object]', '(-15.230583, 129.494306)', 'Plexus_Site', '39', 'Critical', 'Plexus',  'CSK Ltd.',  '1');">Critical</button></td></tr>
                            <tr class="test testremove" id="Site40"><td class="Fair">&nbsp;&nbsp;8. Plexus_Test_STL<button type="button" class="pull-right  btn btn-warning btn-xs fairbtnwidth" id="site_40" onclick="ChangeColorforSensor('Site40', 'Fair'); ShowSitePopup('[object Object]', '(37.065525, -90.441103)', 'Plexus_Test_STL', '40', 'Fair', '8050 W Florissant',  'CSK Ltd.',  '2');">Fair</button></td></tr>
                            <tr class="test testremove" id="Site36"><td class="Normal">&nbsp;&nbsp;9. SD_Card_Site<button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-success btn-xs" id="site_36" onclick="ChangeColorforSensor('Site36', 'Normal'); ShowSitePopup('[object Object]', '(51.50735, -0.127758)', 'SD_Card_Site', '36', 'Normal', 'Test',  'CSK Ltd.',  '1');">Normal</button></td></tr>
                            <tr class="test testremove" id="Site33"><td class="Normal">&nbsp;&nbsp;10. Sam Test Site<button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-grey btn-xs" id="site_33" onclick="ChangeColorforSensor('Site33', 'Normal'); ShowSitePopup('[object Object]', '(28.084589, 104.979385)', 'Sam Test Site', '33', 'Normal', 'TMTC, Hyderabad',  'CSK Ltd.',  '1');">Normal</button></td></tr>
                            <tr class="test testremove" id="Site44"><td class="Normal">&nbsp;&nbsp;11. T123<button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-success btn-xs" id="site_44" onclick="ChangeColorforSensor('Site44', 'Normal'); ShowSitePopup('[object Object]', '(37.061973, -97.038371)', 'T123', '44', 'Normal', 'XXX',  'TestCmp',  '0');">Normal</button></td></tr>
                            <tr class="test testremove" id="Site3"><td class="Normal">&nbsp;&nbsp;12. TMTC_Subscriber_Site<button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-grey btn-xs" id="site_3" onclick="ChangeColorforSensor('Site3', 'Normal'); ShowSitePopup('[object Object]', '(55.632955, 99.223156)', 'TMTC_Subscriber_Site', '3', 'Normal', 'Begumpet, Hyderabad',  'CSK Ltd.',  '1');">Normal</button></td></tr>
                            <tr class="test testremove" id="Site42"><td class="Critical">&nbsp;&nbsp;13. TestSite01<button type="button" class="pull-right  btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="site_42" onclick="ChangeColorforSensor('Site42', 'Critical'); ShowSitePopup('[object Object]', '(62.3919, 6.598008)', 'TestSite01', '42', 'Critical', 'Vijayawada',  'CSK Ltd.',  '1');">Critical</button></td></tr>
                           
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You selector has some issues there:

```
`.table tbody tr td:nth-child(1):contains(${search})`
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            // Search on name column only
            $('#SearchValue').keyup(function () {
                // Search Text
                var search = $(this).val();

                // Hide all table tbody rows
                $('table tbody tr').hide();
                const select2 = `.table tbody tr td:nth-child(1):contains(${search})`;
                // Count total search result
                var len = $(select2).length;
                console.log(select2);

                if (len > 0) {
                    // Searching text in columns and show match row
                    $(select2).each(function () {
                        $(this).closest('tr').show();
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $('table tbody tr').show();
                }

            });

        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/p34bfyzw/